# Architecture question - reverse client and server

Tags: c#, .net, angular, architecture

I have an angular app working against .NET core centralized backend
Upon request from the angular client, This backend needs to pull out information from 3rd party databases (multiple ones) located in other network. Each client is assigned to a specific database.
The database is not accessible directly, nor its possible to put an API that will return relevant information from that db due to network restriction.
It is, however possible to put an agent next to each such db that will be able to communicate with the backend (outgoing connection).

So one possibility is obviously to sync the required info to the central db.
This is problematic due to many reasons, mainly the amount of the information is very large, out of which only small portion would be used.

The 2nd possibility would be to cause the agent to return information on demand - in real time.

Ideal would be the following scenario:

1. Angular client calls endpoint X on the backend
2. Backend calls endpoint X on the "agent" (not directly, but rather making the agent respond with information to the backend
3. Information is returned to the client

I guess the backend serves like a proxy between the client and the agent, but there is the issue of agent not being accessible from the backend.

What would be the best approach to implement something like this, without re-inventing the wheel?
Given the fact the amount of APIs is not very small, and agent respond has to be in real time

Comment: Turn it into a network problem, by using some form of point-to-point vpn?

Comment: Its not possible, since each such agent goes to a different customer and should be lightweight to install, without having to configure any public ip or other network config to work. Should work as a client in network sense,not as server

Comment: You need to pick a protocol for fetching data. If that's http & json, then you'll need to proxy requests over something. Solve that problem and you can then use whatever tools you like.

Comment: Yes I realize i can do this using raw tcp sockets for that matter and make up my own protocol for data exchange between the server and the agent, and somehow queue the client's request until I get the response from the agent. I'm just looking for something simular to this ready made instead of writing all of it from scratch